How can well-documented phenomena with predictive implications for pricing exist?
This is a general question. I will give an example:
The cross-sectional seasonality effect is the phenomenon where assets' average past returns during specific time intervals (e.g., same weekday) predict their future returns in those same intervals.
Why does this effect persist in the market? In theory, if traders know about this anomaly, they would continually exploit it, driving the market to a point where the effect no longer exists. In general, what prevents this from happening? What factors allow a price predictive phenomenon to remain, despite being well-known?

Hi: I think the question is more how does one determine if the effect persists in the market ? Or, even did the effect exist in the first place ? Note that anectodal evidence should not count because there's always luck and random-ness playing their roles. So, I think you should check those things ( by either doing your own study or finding research that's been done )  before you delve into your question. Not that it's not an interesting question. I just think you're jumping the gun.

I think you mean time-series seasonality and not cross-sectional?

@KaiSqDist by cross-sectional seasonality I was referring to this paper. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/341315224_Seasonality_in_the_Cross-Section_of_Cryptocurrency_Returns
While this paper is about cryptocurrencies specificially, the effect has also been documented in other classes.

@markleeds, from the introduction of the paper mentioned in my comment above:
"The cross-sectional seasonality effect is one of the most powerful and pervasive asset pricing anomalies. First discovered by
Heston and Sadka (2008), it implies that assets with the highest (lowest) average same-calendar month return tend to overperform
(underperform) in the future."

Hi: I printed it out but I don't have time to read it right now. Assuming it exists, there are two possibilities. 1) The persistence (  I would check at a later period and see if what they say still holds ) is due to the lack of efficiency in the crypto  market. 2) The persistence is gone because the crypto market has become more efficient. Actually, there's another reason. Heston and Sadka retired because they found it, exploited it and continue to exploit it !!!!!!! No one else believes the paper or it's not popular so has been read by only a few.

I would like to read it and do plan on reading it in the future so thank you for reference.
